# localStorage not storing a stringed Array of JSON objects

Tags: json, html, jquery-mobile, local-storage

I have a back-end  application spitting JSON data like this:

```
[{"id":1,"line_number":"604"},{"id":2,"line_number":"610"}]
```

My mobile app is storing that array as a string using localStorage, in Jquery-Mobile's mobileinit function:

```
localStorage.variable = getBusesList();
```

In turn, that function, does the following:

```
function getBusesList(){
  var busesJSONArray = [];
  $.getJSON('someURL', function(data){  
    $.each(data, function(key, value){
        busesJSONArray.push( { id: value.id, line_number: value.line_number } );
    });
  });
  var JSONObject = {
    buses: busesJSONArray
  };

  alert("busesJSONArray :" + busesJSONArray);
  alert(" getBusesList Done: " + JSON.stringify(JSONObject));
  return JSON.stringify(JSONObject);
}
```

The getJSON function is working as it should. The problem should not be there.
It should return a string containing the array of Objects. This works if I type the commands directly in the browser console. But if run the mobile app the first alert has: "busesJSONArray: " and the second one has: "getBusesList Done: {"buses":[]}".

In effect:

```
>localStorage.buses
"{"buses":[]}"
```

This is weird. Any hint for what's going on would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using `$.getJSON` that is asynchronous, only the code inside the callback function will have the information retrieved from the URL.

This code:

```
var JSONObject = {
  buses: busesJSONArray
};

alert("busesJSONArray :" + busesJSONArray);
alert(" getBusesList Done: " + JSON.stringify(JSONObject));
return JSON.stringify(JSONObject);
```

won't have the information that was recovered in the `$.getJSON` call, so it wont do what you expect, you need to rework your logic to work inside the callback.

It works in the console because you wait for the async call to finish before entering the other commands.